Can every positive odd integer $\geq 3$ be written as the sum of a power of $2$ and a prime number?

Can every positive odd integer $\geq 3$ be written as the sum of a
power of $2$ and a prime number?

For example,
$$ 3 = 2^0 + 2 $$
$$ 27 = 2^4 + 11 $$
$$ 31 = 2^1 + 29 $$
$$123 =  2^4 + 107$$
Unless I made a mistake, it seems to be true for the first few hundred odd numbers, but this does not mean it is not false for large numbers, which I will today write some program code to check.
You cannot say it is definitely true by the condition of Bertrand's Postulate, that is, $a_{n+1} < 2a_n,$ because $3,5,9,17,\ldots$ is a sequence where $15$ cannot be written as the sum of a power of two and a smaller number in the sequence.

There are three possibilities:

There is a counter-example, or

The proposition is true for some elementary number theory reason or other reasons like pigeonhole principle or mathematical induction, which I do not currently see, or

This is a "hard" (possibly open) problem.



Let $N$ be large. There are $\approx \log_2 N$ powers of $2$ that are $\leq N.$ There are $\approx \frac{N}{\ln N}$ primes $\leq N.$ But I'm not sure what this says about $\{2^j+p:j\in\mathbb{N}, p\in\mathbb{P} \}.$

Seems to be false for infinitely many values, as claimed here. However, I couldn't find a link to an actual counterexample.

Insight is contained in this question

Isn't 127 a counterexample?

@schiepy Yes it is!
